# Implement Incrementing Counter in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, increment

So I need to implement essentially an auto-increment column.  I have a column in one table that has an int that will act as the counter, and there will be another table with a corresponding number of rows, each row having it's own counter.  I thought this would be fairly simple to implement, but after doing some research I found a few forums where they mention there could be issues in situations like this if multiple transactions were running roughly at the same time, even by running the select,update, & insert in one transaction

After looking into though it seemed to me that if I used the OUTPUT clause to grab the new value the first table is getting updated with, I could avoid that issue entirely.

So this is the T-SQL I'm thinking of.  Should this be okay for my situation?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @tblCtrs table (Ctr int)
DECLARE @CtrVal INT

UPDATE Table1
SET Ctr = Ctr+1
OUTPUT inserted.Ctr INTO @CtrVals
WHERE id=<whatever id value>

SET @CtrVal = (SELECT TOP(1) Ctr FROM @tblCtrs)

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (Ctr, ....)
VALUES( @CtrVal, ....)

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the concern is that concurrent transactions could cause unintended results with the counter value.  You know how to manage the counter values just fine, it's just a matter of whether or not some other transaction could read/modify at same time.  If that understanding is correct, that's what isolation levels are for.  Depending upon how the data is accessed/stored (e.g. can there be multiple records with the same <whatever id value> or is that unique?) and application requirements (e.g. is it OK if <whatever id value> is not unique and there is insert of new record that is not updated due to timing) you should [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's it.  It looks like REPEATABLE READ is what I need.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Ok I might just be second guessing, but would this still be necessary for this situation?  If I had two of these transaction running at the same, the first one would acquire the lock, then read the original value, increment it, store it, then output the inserted table into the table parameter.  Now that I think about it the Insert statement doesn't even need to be in the same transaction as the update, so long as I'm able to Update the table value and get the new value without another update interfering with it, or being affected by the first update transaction.  That should work right?

Comment: It's a matter of desired behavior when rows inserted at same time.  Simple example:
BEGIN TRAN T1
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID='x'
...
<other work here>
...
COMMIT

Now at the same time as the <other work>

INSERT INTO 
MyTable (ID, ...)
VALUES ('x'...)

Depending on the isolation level, the insert may or may not be blocked until T1 is either committed or rolled back. Does it need to be?  I.e. does <other work> need to operate on *all* records with ID='x' within chronological scope of that transaction or OK if not? Would having ctr of different values for same ID be OK?

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to use Identity columns, you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to find the Identity value of the last inserted record like the following:

```
DECLARE 
@ParentData varchar(20) = 'ParentData1',
@ChildData varchar(20) = 'ChildData1',
@ParentID int

DECLARE @ParentTable table (ParentId int IDENTITY(1, 1), ParentData Varchar(20))
DECLARE @ChildTable table (ChildId int IDENTITY(1,1), ParentId int, ChildData varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @ParentTable 
    (ParentData)
VALUES
    (@ParentData)

SET @ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO @ChildTable
    (ParentId, ChildData)
VALUES
    (@ParentID, @ChildData)

SET @ChildData = 'ChildData1,1'
INSERT INTO @ChildTable
    (ParentId, ChildData)
VALUES
    (@ParentID, @ChildData)

SET @ParentData = 'ParentData2'
SET @ChildData = 'ChildData2'

INSERT INTO @ParentTable 
    (ParentData)
VALUES
    (@ParentData)

INSERT INTO @ChildTable
    (ParentId, ChildData)
VALUES
    (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @ChildData)


SELECT * FROM @ParentTable
SELECT * FROM @ChildTable
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I did consider identity columns, but the issue is Table1 will have a row, and each have it's own counter, so Table2 will each have it's own sequence as well.  Thanks though.  I always forget about SCOPE_IDENTITY()